# web2py sqlform error

Tags: web2py

I am new at web2py and i am struggling with it

I am trying to crate a registration and login stuff. In models I have the following code where I create tabel for new users

```
usersdb = DAL('postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost/'+ request.vars['school'], migrate=True)
auth = Auth(usersdb, hmac_key=Auth.get_or_create_key())
usersdb.define_table(
    'users',
    Field('first_name', length=128, default=''),
    Field('last_name', length=128, default=''),
    Field('email', length=128, default='', unique=True),
    Field('address', length=256, default=''),
    Field('postcode', length=128, default=''),
    Field('city', length=128, default=''),
    Field('password', 'password', length=512, readable=False, label='Password'),
    Field('registration_key', length=512, writable=False, readable=False, default=''),
    Field('reset_password_key', length=512, writable=False, readable=False, default=''),
    Field('registration_id', length=512, writable=False, readable=False, default=''),
    format='%(first_name)s %(last_name)s')
```

So now in controler I have the following code:

```
usersdb = DAL('postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost/'+ request.vars['school'], migrate=True)
auth = Auth(usersdb, hmac_key=Auth.get_or_create_key())
auth.settings.registration_requires_approval = True
form = SQLFORM(usersdb.users)
if form.process(session=None, formname='test').accepted:
    response.flash = 'form accepted'
elif form.errors:
    response.flash = 'form has errors'
else:
    response.flash = 'please fill the form'
 # Note: no form instance is passed to the view

 #set sample validator (do not allow empty nor duplicate names)
return dict(form=form,config=config)
```

The error is loged at SQLFORM (usersdb.users).
 'users'

I don't know how actually this stuff works (connecting database to controler). I am hacking a code written by smb. else.

Thank you for any advice or short explanation.

Bye

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not repeat the definition of `userdb` or `auth` in the controller. Model files are executed on every request (except for conditional model files), and the controller is executed in an environment that contains any objects defined in the models. In your controller, you are overwriting the original `userdb` object with a fresh one, and you are defining `auth` again but not re-creating the "users" table -- hence there is no longer a "users" table on `userdb`.

Just remove the `userdb` and `auth` definitions from the controller.

Comment: But in return, how do I get the form then? I guess with SQLFORM I do that, but if I remove userdb, I receive an error

Comment: If you have truly defined `usersdb` in a model file (i.e., a file in the /models folder), then it will be available globally in any controller. If it is not, then you have not properly defined it in a model file. What error do you get?

Comment: So i created a auth database in model/db.py auth = Auth(db, hmac_key=Auth.get_or_create_key())
    auth.define_tables() and in controler I only have function user return dict(form=auth()). I copied from sample of web2py. I recieve an error NameError: global name 'auth' is not defined. I have almost identical code to the sample page of web2py login and register

Comment: `auth` is not a database object. First you have to create a database object (e.g., `db = DAL(...)`). Then you pass the database object to the `Auth()` constructor, and then when you call `auth.define_tables()`, it will add the Auth tables to the db object. Have you defined `db` somewhere. Something is wrong in your code, but I can't say what without seeing it. I recommend posting on the [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!forum/web2py).